# Creating a project end date from available data

Tags: excel, agile-project-management

Struggling to get my head around this little problem.

It’s almost a burn down chart, but not quite.

I would like to create an Excel graph predicting when a project will complete based on a data. I feel like it should be possible but need some direction.

This is a project I have inherited so apologies for the gaps in data.

Ok, I have a number of tasks/issues/stories required to complete the project. Each of these has an estimated time required in days. And consequently I also have a total number of days figure.

I also have some data for available development resources. (5 developers * (number of days working days - holidays))*80% = effective hours per month.

And I feel that from this data I should be able to calculate on which data the project will complete.

Am I missing something in the theory/formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out critical path analysis and gantt charts

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to consider is *discovery*.

As the team does the work they will occasionally find things they missed in planning that they need to do to complete the project.

To estimate the impact of this you could look at how much discovery has happened on the project so far.

Say, for example, the team 'discovered' 1 story for every ten they planned. That could give you an idea of what might happen during what remains of the project.